# Is it safe practice to dynamically render javascript using Twig?

Tags: javascript, twig, silex

I'm using Silex with Twig. My Twig template processes data passed in through the Silex side and renders Javascript based off of the data.

Is this good practice? I couldn't find anything about it online.

I thought about just passing the data from the Silex side straight to the front-end and processing it there, but I already started the implementation that renders Javascript through a Twig Template.

Thanks for the advice guys!

Comment: That depends on how you do it. You'll want to sanitize any potentially problematic input so a user having a name like `O'Dell` doesn't cause trouble because of the `'`.

Comment: It's as much safe as writing regular JS. Of course if it receives data posted from somewhere, you need to sanitize, but it does not add nothing more than already is. I do it all the time, and I haven't had any problems.

Comment: Okay great! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something that's bad practice. I felt like it could have been bad practice to render JS with Twig because it's not static. Good to know dynamically rendered JS is safe, assuming user input is sanitized.

Answer (score 1):

Twig is just a view layer. No matter if you render it directly from your programming language or through templating engine - it always gonna be available in the user interface (probably only for logged in users, depending on scenarios). I does not make much difference as long as you follow data hiding principle - expose only necessary data to the client.

Comment: `probably only for logged in users, depending on scenarios`: If you are using a caching method, this could be tricky though

Comment: @darkbee i don't really see how, could you elaborate a bit? I'm curious

Comment: Generating the `javascript` / `html` with `twig` would mean you would have access to every variable at that point e.g. the logged in user. Lets say you a have a shopping cart which display the current items in that cart. `pre-twig` you would have created an `ajax` call which fetched the current count and update the `GUI`, but with `twig` you just could fetch the current with something like `{{ get_cart().countItems() }}`. This sounds nice untill you wrap your site with `HTTP` caching to lower the load on your server. Doing so would show the current cart count from user `X` to user `Y`

Comment: oooh, this way. That's a very fair point. Well, seemingly i kind of miss the point of generating the javascript on server-side. For me it sounds a bit odd anyways and only thing i can imagine happen is just serving various sets of JS modules for various routes. And i would take care of that by just using some front-end router. Anyways, thank you for your time, @DarkBee